# PHP Group by and list all the other column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table:
[image]

The select db is:

```
$select_table2 = '
SELECT e.product_clicks
     , e.product_id
     , e.website_url
     , u.name
     , u.product_id 
 FROM `oc_aa_affiliatecollclicktracking` AS e 
 LEFT      
 JOIN  `'.DB_PREFIX.'product_description` AS u 
    ON e.product_id = u.product_id 
 GROUP 
    BY e.website_url';
```

This will group it but won't list all product_id

I get:

```
http://127.0.01
        36
```

I'd like to group it but see all the product_id

```
http://127.0.01
    36
    40
    33
```

Comment: you can't. `group by` will "collapse" similar records where the grouped values are the same. either select them out as separate records, or use hacks like `group_concat()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$select_table2 = 'SELECT `product_id` FROM `oc_aa_affiliatecollclicktracking` WHERE website_url LIKE '%http%';
```

if you dont want to repeat `product_id`

```
$select_table2 = 'SELECT DISTINCT(`product_id`) FROM `oc_aa_affiliatecollclicktracking` WHERE website_url LIKE '%http%';
```